# How to handle over variables in nested functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When **calling an function** like in my case "*setState(...)*" which has a form where the **first argument is a function**, I wonder how to pass a local variable over to this function.

Here is my example:

```
let myDate = new Date();

this.setState((myDate) => {
    return {
       date: myDate
   }
})
```

As you can see I'm using the [arrow-notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two variables called `myDate`.

- The one in the wider scope defined on line one
- The one local to the arrow function defined in its arguments on line three

The second one masks the first one.

Just don't do that so the function has access to the one in the wider scope.

```
this.setState(() => {
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the parameter in your setState is unnecessary, simply call the variable in your setState and that will work.

```
let myDate = new Date();

 this.setState(() => {
    return {
       date: myDate
   }
})
```